# ¿Como agregar el plugin jQueri-ui autocomplete en mi CRUD-MODAL?

Tags: jquery, modal, crud, autocomplete

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente; estoy utilizando el plugin de **jQuery-ui autocomplete**, el objetivo del *plugin* es bastante obvio al ingresar una o varias letras deberá devolverme las opciones que almacene en el script. Mi código funciona perfectamente en el `body`, pero no funciona dentro de mi **CRUD MODAL**.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
          var ValoresAutocompletar = [
                "ARGENTINA",
                "ARGELIA",
                "PERU",
                "BRASIL",
                "POLONIA"
            ];

          $("#autocom").autocomplete({
          source: ValoresAutocompletar

          })

    })
</script>
```

---

Aquí un ejemplo exitoso en el `body`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Mi código modalcrud:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCRUD" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabelLarge" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabelLarge"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
           <form id="formPersonas" id="form_subir">
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                           <div class="form-group">  
           <form>
               <label for="autocom"><strong>NIVEL</strong></label>
                   <input type="text" size="25"  id="autocom" placeholder="Escribe" class="form-control">
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: A que te refieres con que no funciona, tiene algún error? no aparece nada?, tienes ejemplos del error que mencionas?

Comment: No aparece nada,en el body si muestra en mi en modal no aparece nada.

Comment: Te comento por que con ese plugin tuve un error parecido, estaba ocupando Bootstrap 4 como front y los datos aparecían sin problemas en el body y en un modal me aparecían esquinados en la esquina superior izquierda y cuando sobreponía el mouse en los resultados desaparecían. Fin de cuentas marcaré tu pregunta por si alguien tiene la solución y para aportar a ella por que yo decidí cambiar la metodología y ocupar un autocomplete desde el server, pero eran datos mas estandarizados. no parece ser tu caso.

Comment: Gracias, espero alguien pueda ayudarme en este inconveniente.